# Enable version control with Laravel

Tags: git, laravel

I have a Debian stretch server. Here I use the lamp setup.

Until now my usual workflow used to be quite simple. I had a copy of my website on Google Drive, which I edited with sublime text 3.

All changes I instantly uploaded to the server by hand. This was possible, because of small project structure .But it also was quite annoying, because I couldn't develop locally.

Recently I started my first project with Laravel. Now there is on my server this big Laravel project and locally I only have the files I changed or added.

Now I want to adapt a more professional workflow. I need some kind of free and easy VCS. I know I can use xamp to emulate a lamp server. Some questions:

- do my workstation and server need git
- does my client workstation need Laravel

I haven't used git before. My local workstation uses win10.

Comment: Learn git, it`s "must have" for every developer

Comment: follow the instructions https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead

Comment: your two question is simply depends on the circumstances. (1) *does my workstation and server need git*, yes if you decided on *Continuous Integration*, where your server is `master` branch. (2) *does my client workstation need Laravel*, big question, does your client/user do code the laravel?? if no, why he should have one? to put simply, where you code, you will need `git`.